# Alt Solution: A forest contains 20 elk.

Tags: probability

A forest contains 20 elk, of which 5 are captured, tagged, and then released. A certain time later, 4 of the 20 elk are captured. What is the probability that 2 of these 4 have been tagged? What assumptions are you making?

**Solution:**

$ P\{\text{2 of 4 tagged}\} = {{5 \choose 2}{15 \choose 2} \over {20 \choose 4}}$

$= 0.2167$

**Question:**

How would you solve this differently using conditional probability? What would the argument/expression be?

**To clarify:**

I am trying to see if I can use Bayes formula to solve this or something like the following:

Let $A$ be the set containing all 15 unmarked elk.

Let $B$ be the set containing all of the 5 tagged elk.

$A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Let $C$ be the set containing the 4 chosen elk so that $C$ spans both $A$ and $B$ and $ A^c \bigcap B^c \bigcap C = \emptyset $ , then

$ P(C) = P[ (C \bigcap C) \bigcup (A \bigcap A^c) \bigcup (B \bigcap B^c) ] $

$ = P(CAB) + P(CAB^c) + P(CA^cB) + P(CA^cB^c) $

$= \emptyset + P(CAB^c)+P(CA^cB) + \emptyset$

$= P(CA) + P(CB)$

$= { {15 \choose 4} \over {20 \choose 4} } + { {5 \choose 4} \over {20 \choose 4} }$

$=0.2828$

I think this works out $P(C | A \bigcup B)$

Comment: Do you know the capture-recapture formula?

Comment: No. I just looked it up in [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture), but this seems to estimate the total population.

Comment: The 'original version' of the problem states that the $\frac{marked / in / first / sample}{population / size}$ is approximately $\frac{marked / in  / second / sample}{caught / in /second /sample}$. Using this, you can rearrange the formula for "marked in second sample".

Answer (score 1):

The statement of the question implies that there are only 20 elk in the forest, and that this number is fixed (no births or deaths).  The 5 elk tagged are distinct members of this population, and *any given elk in the population is equally likely to have been tagged.*

Similarly, the 4 elk recaptured at a later time are distinct members of the population, and *any given elk is equally likely to have been recaptured, regardless of whether it had been previously tagged*.  This statement in italics is the primary assumption in the question.

With this in mind, we can regard the previous incident of tagging as having identified some elk as having a property of interest; e.g., it partitions the population into two mutually exclusive groups:  those 5 elk that have been tagged, and those 15 elk that have not.  The random sampling (recapturing) of 4 elk without replacement from this population, then, can occur in any of $\binom{20}{4}$ ways, representing the total number of possible elementary outcomes.

The number of desired outcomes is counted by considering that in order for the desired outcome to occur, exactly $2$ of the $4$ recaptured elk must be tagged, which implies $4 - 2 = 2$ of the recaptured elk are untagged.  As there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ tagged elk from the $5$ previously tagged, and $\binom{15}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ untagged elk from the $15$ untagged elk, and these choices can be made independently of each other, the total number of desired outcomes is $\binom{5}{2} \binom{15}{2}$.

---

The issue with your solution is that you've not defined your events clearly with respect to counting the desired probability.  For example, $\Pr[C]$ makes no sense.  You define $C$ as a set, but it needs to be an **event**.  This lack of clarity causes your computation to lack meaning.

Rather, let us define a random variable $X$ that represents the number of tagged elk obtained in the sample of $4$ recaptured elk.  Then $$\Pr[X = 2]$$ is the desired probability and $X = 2$ is the desired event.  If we line up the four recaptured elk in order of capture, let's label them $(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4)$, where $e_i = 0$ if the $i^{\rm th}$ elk is untagged, and $e_i = 1$ if the $i^{\rm th}$ elk is tagged.  We can see that we get $X = 2$ in exactly $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways, explicitly $$(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4) \in \{(0,0,1,1), (0,1,0,1), (0,1,1,0), (1,0,0,1), (1,0,1,0), (1,1,0,0)\}.$$  In the first case, we are interested in computing $$\Pr[(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4) = (0,0,1,1)].$$  This can be done by conditioning on each elk captured, in order of their capture.  For example, $$\Pr[e_1 = 0] = \frac{15}{20},$$ since when the first elk is recaptured, there are $15$ untagged elk to choose from out of $20$.  Then $$\Pr[e_2 = 0 \mid e_1 = 0] = \frac{15 - 1}{20 - 1} = \frac{14}{19},$$ since once the first elk is recaptured and it is untagged, there are $14$ untagged elk remaining out of $19$ total.  Next, $$\Pr[e_3 = 1 \mid (e_1,e_2) = (0,0)] = \frac{5}{18},$$ since there are $5$ tagged elk still available if the first two were untagged.  Finally, $$\Pr[e_4 = 1 \mid (e_1, e_2, e_3) = (0,0,1)] = \frac{4}{17}.$$  Thus the probability of the first case is $$\Pr[(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4) = (0,0,1,1)] = \frac{15}{20}\frac{14}{19}\frac{5}{18}\frac{4}{17}.$$  Similarly, we can work out the probabilities of the other five cases, which are $$\left\{ \frac{15(5)(14)(4)}{20(19)(18)(17)}, \frac{15(5)(4)(14)}{20(19)(18)(17)}, \frac{5(15)(14)(4)}{20(19)(18)(17)}, \frac{5(15)(4)(14)}{20(19)(18)(17)}, \frac{5(4)(15)(14)}{20(19)(18)(17)} \right\}.$$  These of course are all equivalent, since the product in the numerator is just rearranged in the order of their factors.  This should not come as a surprise.  The total probability is therefore $$\Pr[X = 2] = \frac{6(15)(14)(5)(4)}{20(19)(18)(17)},$$ having counted the six mutually exclusive cases comprising the desired probability.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a concise solution, you have definitely given me a different perspective on it. I believe though that your solution is a thorough explanation on the first solution given.

My question now is, is this the only approach to this problem or can one find some other set notation form where it is expressed algebraically i.e. is there an alternate solution?

Comment: @JohnnyM I have given two solutions; the first is based on the counting argument for a hypergeometric distribution; the second is based on conditional probability.

Comment: Yes thank you very much, though I have no clue what hyper-geometric distribution is. Looking at your second solution it seems to be a true dissection of the first one and though the approach differs the argument seems the same (but that's probably just me). Consider for a moment that you just started Chapter 3 of a Sheldon Ross, with your current knowledge would it be possible to formulate a solution to this problem given that this knowledge only extends to Bayes Theorem (given examples excluded)?